# Prusa MK3s+ potential extrusion problem

Tags: prusa-i3, prusaslicer

I've recently tried printing something I've printed multiple times but this time it isn’t printing much at all. It seems to inly be printing a very small film of filament rather than a solid layer in places and even on the solid base layer the first time I tried printing it. I'm not sure whether it could be an under extrusion problem or I might even have to raise the z calibration. Has anyone seen this before and does anyone have any possible solutions? Would be much appreciated I need to set this print going ASAP

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it was due to the Z axis calibration on my Prusa MK3S+ so I started a "First Layer Calibration" and reset the variable previously used to get a more accurate calibration